# RVM showing 'clr' and bash errors with every command

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, rvm

My OS is OSX 10.9.4, and every time I run a Ruby Version Manager command I am seeing a bunch of errors, though the command itself still seems to run, often with a warning at the end. These are the messages that appear on every command:

```
rvm_error_clr=: No such file or directory
rvm_warn_clr=: No such file or directory
rvm_debug_clr=: No such file or directory
rvm_notify_clr=: No such file or directory
rvm_reset_clr=: No such file or directory
-bash: eval: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: eval: line 8: `ssh-agent __rvm_awk() { \awk "$@" || return $?; }'
-bash: eval: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: eval: line 8: `ssh-agent __rvm_cp() { \cp "$@" || return $?; }'
-bash: eval: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: eval: line 8: `ssh-agent __rvm_date() { \date "$@" || return $?; }'
-bash: eval: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: eval: line 8: `ssh-agent __rvm_find() { \find "$@" || return $?; }'
-bash: eval: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: eval: line 8: `ssh-agent __rvm_sed() { \sed "$@" || return $?; }'
-bash: eval: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: eval: line 8: `ssh-agent __rvm_tail() { \tail "$@" || return $?; }'
-bash: eval: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: eval: line 8: `ssh-agent __rvm_tar() { \tar "$@" || return $?; }'
-bash: eval: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: eval: line 8: `ssh-agent __rvm_xargs() { \xargs "$@" || return $?; }'
```

Here is the full output of the `rvm get stable` command:

```
My-MBA:~ me$ rvm get stable
rvm_error_clr=: No such file or directory
rvm_warn_clr=: No such file or directory
rvm_debug_clr=: No such file or directory
rvm_notify_clr=: No such file or directory
rvm_reset_clr=: No such file or directory
-bash: eval: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: eval: line 8: `ssh-agent __rvm_awk() { \awk "$@" || return $?; }'
-bash: eval: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: eval: line 8: `ssh-agent __rvm_cp() { \cp "$@" || return $?; }'
-bash: eval: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: eval: line 8: `ssh-agent __rvm_date() { \date "$@" || return $?; }'
-bash: eval: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: eval: line 8: `ssh-agent __rvm_find() { \find "$@" || return $?; }'
-bash: eval: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: eval: line 8: `ssh-agent __rvm_sed() { \sed "$@" || return $?; }'
-bash: eval: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: eval: line 8: `ssh-agent __rvm_tail() { \tail "$@" || return $?; }'
-bash: eval: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: eval: line 8: `ssh-agent __rvm_tar() { \tar "$@" || return $?; }'
-bash: eval: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: eval: line 8: `ssh-agent __rvm_xargs() { \xargs "$@" || return $?; }'
Downloading https://get.rvm.io
Downloading https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/stable.tar.gz

Upgrading the RVM installation in /Users/me/.rvm/
    RVM PATH line found in /Users/me/.profile /Users/me/.bashrc /Users/me/.zshrc.
    RVM sourcing line found in /Users/me/.bash_profile /Users/me/.zlogin.
Upgrade of RVM in /Users/me/.rvm/ is complete.

# You,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   We sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne, Michal & team.

In case of problems: http://rvm.io/help and https://twitter.com/rvm_io

Upgrade Notes:

  * No new notes to display.

rvm_error_clr=: No such file or directory
rvm_warn_clr=: No such file or directory
rvm_debug_clr=: No such file or directory
rvm_notify_clr=: No such file or directory
rvm_reset_clr=: No such file or directory
-bash: eval: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: eval: line 8: `ssh-agent __rvm_awk() { \awk "$@" || return $?; }'
-bash: eval: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: eval: line 8: `ssh-agent __rvm_cp() { \cp "$@" || return $?; }'
-bash: eval: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: eval: line 8: `ssh-agent __rvm_date() { \date "$@" || return $?; }'
-bash: eval: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: eval: line 8: `ssh-agent __rvm_find() { \find "$@" || return $?; }'
-bash: eval: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: eval: line 8: `ssh-agent __rvm_sed() { \sed "$@" || return $?; }'
-bash: eval: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: eval: line 8: `ssh-agent __rvm_tail() { \tail "$@" || return $?; }'
-bash: eval: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: eval: line 8: `ssh-agent __rvm_tar() { \tar "$@" || return $?; }'
-bash: eval: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: eval: line 8: `ssh-agent __rvm_xargs() { \xargs "$@" || return $?; }'
WARNING:
      Errors sourcing '/Users/me/.rvm/scripts/base'.
      RVM will likely not work as expected.
```

Nothing like this was happening when I first started using RVM. It's been a while since I used it and I'm not sure what changed to cause these errors. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

***EDIT***

Output of `cd /Users/me/.rvm/scripts` followed by `ls -al base`:

```
My-MBA:my_app me$ cd /Users/me/.rvm/scripts
My-MBA:scripts me$ ls -al base
-rwxr-xr-x  1 me  staff  2879 Sep 10 10:32 base
```

Output of `cd ..` (back to /.rvm) and `ls -dal scripts`:

```
My-MBA:scripts me$ cd ..
My-MBA:.rvm me$ ls -dal scripts
drwxr-xr-x  53 me  staff  1802 Sep  1 08:07 scripts
```

Comment: Can you post the output of doing: `$ cd /Users/you/.rvm/scripts` and then `$ ls -al base`?  And...then maybe `$ cd ..` and `$cd ls -dal scripts`.  Oh yeah, ALWAYS post your OS.

Comment: sure thing, added the outputs and OS at top (OSX 10.9.4)

Comment: **It's been a while since I used it and I'm not sure what changed to cause these errors** You installed a new version of rvm--that's what changed! The command `rvm get stable` means: go out on the web and retrieve the most recent stable version of rvm and install it.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, try the rvm mailing list or IRC chat, or as directed in the error message: http://rvm.io/help and https://twitter.com/rvm_io.

Comment: Your permissions are the same as my setup, so nothing obvious there.